# Issue with logging out in NetSuite

Tags: caching, logout, netsuite

We have an SCA Mont Blanc site setup with product MSRP showing to users who aren't logged in, and specific customer prices showing to users who are logged in.

But we've run into a strange glitch whereby a user who logs out will still see his or her specific pricing. This is an issue because it confuses customers into thinking MSRP is lower than what it really is and typically happens the 2nd time a user logs into the website from within the same browser terminal (i.e. if you open a browser, log in and log out, the problem doesn't appear... but if you login again the site doesn't logout properly).

The only solution I have now is to tell users to clear their browser cache after they log out, but some people aren't used to doing that and it's not really how the site should operate.

Does anyone have a work-around or fix for this problem? Is there something I can add to the logout.ssp file to help resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to clear the cookies related to your site as explained [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/clear-all-cookies-from-a-website/224983/2).

Comment: Is that the best way to go about fixing this? Can you provide more details?

Comment: NetSuite actually fixed this issue on their end.